# Is there a way to control the title for a Content-type: text/plain document?

Tags: http, http-headers, content-type

In a Content-type: text/plain document, is there any way to control the page title of the document (i.e. the title shown in the web browser's title bar)?

Obviously there's no way to control this from the content, but basically the equivalent effect of the `<title>` tag in HTML.

I was hoping there'd be an HTTP server response, similar to `Content-type: text/plain` to control the content title that might influence the title. e.g. `Content-Description:` or even an `X-` command that might be browser specific. What I'd be hoping for is something like `Content-Title:` (which doesn't exist I don't think)

Comment: I have this problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has gone unanswered for 5 years, so it seems the best I can do is create an html page with a title, and have it just contain a full screen `<iframe>` that loads the .txt file.

This Seems to work on chrome and firefox, so I'm going with this unless something better comes along..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HTML Title</title>
  <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
      iframe { border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="foo.txt"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```